# why is around my mouses eye red?

Tags: eye-disease

I noticed that around my mouses eye that it is red. I did change the bedding to paper because I used pine wood but I found out that was not good for them. I would take her to the vet but they do not treat mice where I live. [image]

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! If you are in actual worry about the health of your pet, then a vet is your first address. do not wait for strangers from the internet. You could send this photo to a vet more far away, or call one. In general a lots of white animals have red/pink skin under the fur. But I am not an expert to see, if it is more red than it should be.

Comment: Please read [this related post](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/13610/12501) for a possible answer. This looks like it could be similar, but I'm neither a vet nor an owner of pet mice.